# Attempt to open a closed question.

Tags: support, closed-questions

One of my questions has been closed as not a real question because some people fail to grasp the implied question.  I realise this is a public board and I must cater for all levels, so I have edited the question to make it unmistakably a real question.

How can I resubmit this question to Super User for once again trying to elicit answers?

Comment: -1 for calling me stupid "`some people fail to grasp the implied question`"

Comment: downvote for "implied question" ... objective Q&A man, objective _in your face, hi how you doin_ questions.

Answer (score 13):

Presumably you mean [this](https://superuser.com/questions/220155/view-page-info-in-chrome-closed) question?
Also, if you're not aware; in the way that a question can be closed by vote, it can be reopened by vote - so the correct way to re-ask a closed question is to edit it and get it re-opened.

The original version didn't really ask a question, so the close makes sense to me.
Your latest edit (rev2) is an improvement.

However, you say it in your question above `...fail to grasp the implied question.` , and that's the problem - don't ask implicit questions, they make the question harder to answer and understand (and thus more likely to be closed). As such, I'd (personally) suggest another edit to state *exactly* what you need to find, so the question becomes "How can I find x,y and z of a page in Chrome?".

For example (looking at the FF page info window for some random examples), do you need the Render Mode? The modified date? The file size? The file encoding? The list of RSS feeds (with direct links)? The list of media (with file size, dimensions, previous, URL)? The sites cookies? Number of previous visits? Whether you've saved passwords? And so on...

Basically "useful page and frame info" is still very vague (and useless to anyone without a copy of Firefox handy), and this will put people off answering (and from voting to re-open).

I imagine many of these bits of data are in different places in Chrome (I'm not a Chrome user, so don't know) and so require different answers, so if you can be exact with which elements you need then people can answer with specific responses.

Comment: Thanks @DMA57361, my original question was hurried, as was my edit.  I'll make some time later and try and be more explicit.

Comment: I see lots of unwanted rants instead of a coherent question. Fair to say most people don't want to wade through a rant searching for that elusive question.

Comment: @ProfKaos - Edit it to make it less confrontational "`stupid little dialogue`". Remove anything that deals with your *feelings* "`huge disappointment`"

Answer (score 7):

Your [question](https://superuser.com/questions/220155/view-page-info-in-chrome-closed) is of the form “how do I get program X's feature in program Y”. You've fallen into two traps of such questions, one objective and one emotional.

1. You don't describe program X's feature precisely, so someone who only knows program Y won't know you're after. Granted, in this particular case, there aren't so many Chrome experts who don't know Firefox. But still, it would help if you made a list of the information you're interested in. Maybe Chrome spreads it over several UI elements, or you need multiple extensions, or there are separate feature requests. The way you asked the question, people may refrain from answering because they don't know of an exact equivalent. If you explained better, you might get useful partial answers.
2. You insult program Y (“I get a stupid little dialogue”, “I get a silly little balloon tip”). By extension, you're insulting developers and users of program Y. So you're setting the very people who might help you against you. When they reach this point in the question, chances are they stop reading and either pass on, or vent their anger in a down vote or close vote.

Here's an [example of a good question](https://superuser.com/questions/221116/make-google-chromes-address-bar-prefer-page-titles-to-domain-names-when-offering) on a similar topic.

Answer (score 4):

I'll be blunt here.

> because some people fail to grasp the implied question

We're looking for a straightforward question, not buried questions within nonsensical ranting and name calling. Any of $insert_company_name teh suxx0r because it does include $feature_y or statements like

> If my question isn't explicit enough for some people

will result in a -1 from me and a Vote to close. No exceptions.

Comment: Same here as well...

Answer (score 4):

Congrats, you have caught the attention of a moderator. :)

I like the answer from @DMA57361, so I am not going to duplicate his response.  I think you understand now why it was closed and what you can do to fix it.

As to your approach to asking questions, you need to leave most of your personal feelings out of questions.  No one knows your exact intent or reason behind asking questions on a public web site.  The question in debate and even in this very question, you kind of insult people before they even attempt to answer your question.  If you are looking for good answers,  don't you want to encourage people to answer?  People volunteer their time to answer questions, so lets try and make it as easy for them to do that and keep interpretation to a minimum.

The root goals of this website are explicit questions/answers.

Comment: For the record, getting the attention of a moderator, 90% of the time, is a bad thing for the receiving party :)